# Angular2 typescript promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I'd like to have a generic http get service I did it using the following code:

```
public get(module: String): Promise<any> { 
return this.http.get(module)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Any[])
           .catch(this.handleError);}
```

The problem is that now I'd like to know when the http.get is finished to fire a command and I don't know how to do it.

If I add something to the .then step it doesn't work

```
.then(response => response.json().data as Any[] && alert("HI"))
```

If I add a `.then` after the other `then`, it fires before the http request is fulfilled.

How can I achieve it?

Using dfsq code I'm able to fire alert("HI") but response is undefined. This is the way I use it:

this.dataService.get("myurl").then(response => console.log(response));

I get undefined

Comment: "If I add a .then after the other then, it fires before the http request is fulfilled." can you show this code? that is not how promise chaining works

Comment: @suraj I guess it's `then(alert("Hi"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to add one more `then` block:

```
public get(module: String): Promise<any> { 
  return this.http.get(module)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Any[])
           .then(data => {
             alert("HI") // <---- do something here
             return data
           })
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Make sure you return previous `data` from then block so you pass it further down promise chain.

Comment: Sorry dfsq, the alert("HI") is working but now the response is not working. Why is that? I get undefined from console.log

Comment: response inside the get function returns the response. But outside the function returns undefined.

Comment: Where do you put console.log exactly?